# How can I relaunch Internet Explorer after it is closed using VB Script

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am looking for a VB Script that will automatically restart Internet Explorer for a Kiosk I am working on if IE is closed. This was the older script but is no longer working

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do While True
WshShell.Run """<the path to the executable file>""", 1, True
Loop
```

Problem is with this code is that it just loops through opening IE constantly.

I can't use "NoBrowserClose" in Registry because it prevents the login to Sharepoint sites which is a requirement.

Comment: VB.NET IsNot(VBScript)

Comment: The best way to do it,is to check is Internet Explorer is running or not

case is running so we let the script sleep for a while and check it again. 

case is not running we launch it !

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with VBScript for this script. Is there a line for sleep?

Comment: The other problem is that it doesn't see that IE is running. When IE is running it just opens another windows. So there is still definitely something missing or wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This vbscript can did the trick, just give a try :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessPath,KioskMode
ProcessPath = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
KioskMode = " -K"
'Exit if the script is already running.
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding",VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
    Do   
        Call Main(Array(ProcessPath))
        Call Pause(1) 'Sleep for 1 minute
    Loop   
End If   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Main(colProcessPaths)   
    Dim ProcessPath   
    For Each ProcessPath In colProcessPaths     
        CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Next   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Commandline LIKE " &  CommandLineLike(ProcessName))   
            If .Count = 0 Then    
                With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
                    .Run DblQuote(ProcessPath) & KioskMode
                End With    
            Else    
                Exit Sub    
            End if   
        End With   
    End With   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
'Checks whether a script with the same name as this script is already running
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
'Function to add the double quotes into a variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you Hackoo! I just had to remove the KioskMode line and it does exactly what I need. Thanks!